# Purchasing a SSL certificate for Heroku

Tags: heroku, ssl-certificate

I am planning to add a SSL certificate to my app on Heroku. For that, I am planning to buy a wildcard ssl [certificate](http://www.namecheap.com/ssl-certificates/comodo/essential-ssl-wildcard-certificate.aspx). A requirement for that certificate is that I need to have a "dedicated IP address".

Afaik, I don't think I have a dedicated IP address as I am hosting my code with Heroku and I don't think I can be guaranteed an IP address of that machine.

Am I missing anything? Should I be looking at another kind of SSL certificate?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your domain name is registered and pointing to Heroku as Heroku's documentation advises, then you should be able to get an SSL certificate for that domain name.  Your SSL certificate authority should not require you to enter in an IP address.  I can only speculate that it might say you need a "dedicated IP address" in order to discourage people from trying to get an SSL certificate for their residential cable modem, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This addresses the issue.